# Set class (or any attribute) on Symfony2.4 form

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I'm trying to figure out how to set the class (or any attribute really) on a Symfony2 form created via FormBuilder. I am aware that you can do this via the template for the form itself, but I would still like to know how to do it via `$this->createFormBuilder()` in the controller.

My code is below. I've tried the `setAttribute()` method as you can see in my code, but it has no effect. I initially thought I messed up as I overwrote the default twig form_div_layout.html.twig file, but this was not the case.

```
private function createResolvedForm($id) {
    return $this->createFormBuilder()
                ->setAction($this->generateUrl('system_announcement_resolve', array('id' => $id)))
                ->setMethod('PUT')
                ->setAttribute('class', 'resolved-form exempt-from-default-ajax')
                ->add('submit', 'submit', array(
                    'label' => 'Mark As Resolved',
                    'attr' => array(
                        'class' => 'btn btn-success btn-xs',
                        'data-toggle' => 'tooltip',
                        'data-placement' => 'top',
                        'title' => 'Resolve Issue #' . $id,
                    )
                ))
                ->getForm();
}
```

To be clear, I'm not having an issue setting the class on the submit button I'm passing in, but rather the actual form itself.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [createFormBuilder](http://api.symfony.com/2.4/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.html#method_createFormBuilder) method has two input parameters

```
public FormBuilder createFormBuilder(mixed $data = null, array $options = array())
```

So in your example you could use the second parameter to set the class on the whole form

```
private function createResolvedForm($id) {
return $this->createFormBuilder(null, array('attr' => array('class' => 'resolved-form exempt-from-default-ajax')))
            ->setAction($this->generateUrl('system_announcement_resolve', array('id' => $id)))
            ->setMethod('PUT')
            ->setAttribute('class', 'resolved-form exempt-from-default-ajax')
            ->add('submit', 'submit', array(
                'label' => 'Mark As Resolved',
                'attr' => array(
                    'class' => 'btn btn-success btn-xs',
                    'data-toggle' => 'tooltip',
                    'data-placement' => 'top',
                    'title' => 'Resolve Issue #' . $id,
                )
            ))
            ->getForm();
}
```

Comment: Wow, it was that simple was it. Thank you so much! Do you by any chance know what the `setAttribute()` method is for then? Marking your answer as accepted!

Comment: I think (but i'm not sure) that those are attributes for the form type object itself, not the html attributes for the element/form

Comment: Interesting... Anyway! Thanks for the help, appreciate it!